# MySQL UPDATE problem

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I know the following MySQL code is not correct can some help me fix this code to use both tables I'm trying to grab the `id` from `learned_skills` and `skill_id` from `users_skills` for `AND skill_id = id`

Here is the MySQL code.

```
SELECT learned_skills.*, users_skills.* 
UPDATE learned_skills
SET skill = '$skill', experience = '$experience', years = '$years'
WHERE user_id = '$user_id'
AND skill_id = id
```

Here is the error I get

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE learned_skills SET skill = 'some_skill', experience = '1 - 2 years' at line 2
```

Comment: How is it incorrect? Is there an error? Does it just not do what you want? How are you invoking this from the calling application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform `UPDATE` operations covering multiple by using the `JOIN` syntax, as in the following example:

```
UPDATE  learned_skills ls
JOIN    user_skills us ON (us.skill_id = ls.id)
SET     skill = '$skill',
        experience = '$experience', 
        years = '$years'
WHERE   us.user_id = '$user_id';
```

Comment: +1 for solving the subsequent problem. It would have been great if the original question had also been answered, though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the select statement on the first line. Remove it and run it seperately and see if that works. Also, qualify both of your tables in a join the way Daniel Vassalo suggested. Otherwise it wont know where to get half the columns from

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) and see the first user comment for help.